# Website routing through CloudFront, PHP Session Problem

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, session, cookies, amazon-cloudfront

I have a website eg: https://abcd.com, routing from **`AWS CloudFront.`** The website is loading properly. However, the **session is not** maintaining **its state**. On every refresh the session gets reset.

The website is developed using Codeigniter, PHP.

If the routing is through **Load Balancer** or directly to the server, the website loads properly and also the session maintains its state. But when routed through **CloudFront**, there is a **session state problem**.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Configure Cloudfront to forward cookies to your load balancer, especially the session_id

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesForwardCookies